# Promise inside promise stuck at "Pending"

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, webpack-2

I'm trying to import a module which exports a Promise:

```
System.import('./details.js').then(details => {
            console.log(details.default); // returns a pending Promise

            details.default.then(m => {
                console.log(m); // never executes, I expect to see 'whatever' here
            })
        });
```

The module I try to import:

```
export default Promise
    .all([
        System.import('./dateHelper'),
        System.import('charts'),
    ])
    .then(mods => Promise.all(mods.map(mod => mod.default)))
    .then(([dateHelper, charts]) => {

     /* ...module content... */

     return 'whatever';
});
```

Have I made a mistake at exported module which is causing a never-ending Promise?

Comment: Have you tried breaking within the details.js to see where it might be getting stuck?

Comment: I've done some testing by disabling modules one by one and it appears that one of them was causing circular dependency - it was trying to load the module by which it was loaded. Pretty disappointing there was not even a single warning about this, though.